# What are the requirements to install TensorFlow with python 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to install TensorFlow with enabled GPU. For this I was using the instructions form [the official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation). First, I created my environment:

```
conda create --name tf_py3_tf_gpu python=3.5
```

then I activated my environment and got the version appropriate for my machine:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
```

then I went ahead and ran pip3 install:

```
(tf_py3_tf_gpu)user~/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages $ pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

but that the error:

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

However, the cluster that I am connecting to does not allow me to use apt-install to install pip3 (if there is a way to install it to an conda environment or something of that style it would be awesome! That I am allowed to do and I do have normal pip).

Anyway I went ahead and did it with normal pip to see if it worked:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

however, it failed with the message:

```
(tf_py3_tf_gpu)user~/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages $ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
Collecting tensorflow==0.10.0rc0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.10.1 in /home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
Collecting protobuf==3.0.0b2 (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Using cached protobuf-3.0.0b2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in /home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf==3.0.0b2->tensorflow==0.10.0rc0)
  Using cached setuptools-26.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: setuptools 25.1.6
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

for some reason it needs `/home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth` which I have no idea why it needs. From this error its unclear to me if the error is due to pip or what the error is or what caused it.

Unfortunately I don't know how install pip3 in the cluster I am connecting to because I do not have the privilege to install it. I did try running the command with normal pip that does not seem to work. Any ideas how to fix this? Or install pip3 or anything of that sort? I am happy to clarify what tools I am allowed to use on the cluster (like I'm allowed to use normal pip and use conda environments).

---

Update:

Actually, it seems to be using a pip version for python 3 (even though the command is not called pip3, not sure if that makes a difference but I ought to mention this):

```
(tf_py3_tf_gpu)user/path $ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /home/user/envs/tf_py3_tf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if `pip` is not in the `bin` folder of your virtualenv.

Try using `/path/to/python -m pip [...]` to make sure you are using the right `pip`

Rename your `~/.local` folder because conda venv try to use them even if they are unrelated to their install

Try `pip install --user [...]`, if all else fails.